# The problem involved WSL, Gunicorn, Docker and Flask

Tags: python, docker, flask, gunicorn, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am working on Windows 10 Pro, Git Bash, Docker Desktop.

Now I have a project which runs a Flask application in Docker through Gunicorn.

The entrypoint in Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn", "-b",":8080","main.py"]
```

When run below command:

```
 docker run -p 127.0.0.1:80:8080 jwt-api-test
```

It shows the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 962, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main.py'; 'main' is not a package
```

If I am right, it is related to gunicorn, which isn't available in Windows.

After googling, it seems wsl is an option. In fact, there is wsl (already being turned on, running in Docker Desktop), info as below:

```
wsl.exe --list --all --verbose
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* docker-desktop-data    Running         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2
```

When I clicked the wsl.exe, and tried to open bash, it didn't work: no error, just nothing happened. I did use shift +restart according to some instructions, but it didn't work either.

May I ask for your help on how to make this Flask application works? Thanks.

Edited: The structure of main.py:

```
JWT_SECRET = os.environ.get('JWT_SECRET', 'abc123abc1234')
LOG_LEVEL = os.environ.get('LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO')

LOG = _logger()
LOG.debug("Starting with log level: %s" % LOG_LEVEL )
APP = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    APP.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:stretch

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn", "-b", ":8080", "main.py"]
```

Comment: How do you run flask in your `main.py`?

Comment: @Raf_W-O, I added the structure of main.py in the original post. Is it what you mean?

Comment: Just in regards to the WSL sub-question - While there's a WSL there for Docker, that's Docker's "private" instance that it uses for its functionality.  You can install a "user" instance from the Microsoft Store - There's Ubuntu WSL, Kali WSL, Debian WSL, and Alpine (among the most supported options).  I'd probably recommend a stock Ubuntu 20.04 install.  That said, I'm not quite sure this is what you need to get the Docker gunicorn running, though.  I would think it would work in the Docker container as is, since it is using a real Linux kernel through WSL.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, thank you for your recommendation. I will give feedback if I will try this later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the rest of your setup is correct (relative paths, ports, Dockerfile, etc.), the problem could be passing `main.py` to `gunicorn`.

Usually you need to pass your Flask variable, i.e in your case replace `"main.py"` in your `ENTRYPOINT` with `"main.APP"` (see [docs](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/run.html#gunicorn))

---

Apart from that: If you get the container running it might be the case that you cannot reach your API. In this case change your gunicorn binding to `"0.0.0.0:8080"` in your `ENTRYPOINT`.

Comment: I have added the Dockerfile in my original post. Gunicorn doesn't work in Windows and has to use a Linux system.

Comment: Since you are running Gunicorn **inside** your Docker container, it should not matter whether you are on Windows. Just be sure that you use Linux containers.

Comment: Thank you. I just googled how to make sure the docker containers is Linux container or not, but didn't get a quite clear answer. May I ask further how to make sure the Docker container is Linux or it is already Linux containers or how to check it, if possible.

Comment: Per default Linux containers are used. To check (or switch) the container type, right click the docker icon in the system tray (see [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#settings)). You should see an option "Switch to Windows containers"; then you are fine. Otherwise, click "Switch to Linux containers".